# Can I plot a normal probability distribution given the number of trials, average, minimum, maximum, and standard deviation?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, graphing-functions

I have the information about processing timing of db transactions.
I was wondering if the info I have is sufficient to plot a normal probability distribution graph.

Data available:

- 560000 hits
- Average processing time: 171 ms
- Minimum processing time: 2 ms
- Maximum processing time: 9909 ms
- Standard deviation: 357 ms

Can I plot the graph according to this information or I need additional info?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you want to plot the probability density function or the cumulative probability function of a normal distribution, you need a location and a scale parameter. But if this is what you want, why do you think that the nomal distribution is the right choice?

Answer (score 2):

A normal distribution does not actually have any minimum and maximum. So you ignore these two parameters. But yes, a normal distribution is [**determined by its mean and standard deviation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), and the formula is given by:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x - \mu)^2 / 2\sigma^2},
$$
where $\mu$ is mean and $\sigma$ is standard deviation.
So just plug in
\begin{align*}
\mu &= 171 \text{ ms} \\
\sigma &= 357 \text{ ms}.
\end{align*}

**HOWEVER:** Note that this normal distribution you get is far from being close to the data you provide! In fact, under this distribution, there is a **31.597% chance** of getting a **negative number**. In contrast, your data has **no negative numbers**. So you might want to seriously consider modeling your data with something *other than a normal distribution*, before just jumping to the conclusion that the data is approximately normal. Bjorn Friedrich in the comments suggests that a [Log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) may be more appropriate.

Comment: The question is, whether the normal distribution makes sense. It would predict negative processing times, which is nonsense.

Comment: I very well know of this *common error*, which is why I ask. Please, look for the log-normal distribution that may be a better choice.

Comment: That the normal distribution has no min/max is not relevant here, as a sample always has a min/max. The question is really: is it useful to compute the parameters? Of course, if mean and standard deviation are available, they give nice estimators. But Björn Friedrich has already pointed out another problem in the question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: The parameter are already *available*. The question is whether to use these for the normal or the log-normal distribution.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I was mixing up the mean and standard deviation. Looking at the numbers again, you're right--this is likely a case of that common pitfall. I added a disclaimer to the answer.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Unless I really don't understand the question, the parameters of the distribution are *not* known. However, estimations of the mean and standard deviation from a sample are known. Absolutely not the same thing.